# Why does my WMS layer overlap the Google Maps v3 logo?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, wms, overlay

I'm using Google Maps v3 as a base layer and on top of that I create an overlay pointing to my WMS (streets and avenues).

A few months ago all works fine, my WMS layer was not overlapping the Google Maps footer (Google logo and copyright), but today it is.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Image Issued]

Here is the code:

```
var
  map,
  stylez = [
    {
      featureType: "administrative",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "landscape",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "transit",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    },{
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Styled", {
    type: 'styled'
  }),
  styledMapOptions = {
    name: "Styled Map"
  },
  styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez, styledMapOptions),
  projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
  displayProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-57.81887, -25.53276, -57.24308, -25.17649).transform(
    displayProjection,
    projection
  );

// avoid pink error tiles
OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";
OpenLayers.ImgPath = "http://js.mapbox.com/theme/dark/";

function init() {

  var
    options = {
      controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
      ],
      projection: projection,
      displayProjection: displayProjection,
      units: "meters",
      numZoomLevels: 12 /* 18 */,
      minZoomLevel: 6,
      maxResolution: 156543.033928041,
      maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-2.003750834E7,-2.003750834E7,2.0037508345578495E7,2.0037508345578495E7)
    };

  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

  // base layer
  var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "Roadmap",
    "http://foo.com:80/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",
    {
      LAYERS: 'Foo',
      STYLES: '',
      format: 'image/png',
      tiled: true,
      transparent: "true",
      tilesOrigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
    },
    {
      isBaseLayer: false,
      opacity: 1.0,
      visibility: true
    }
  );

  tiled.events.register("loadstart", tiled, function() {
      console.debug("Foo, Load Start");
  });

  tiled.events.register("loadend", tiled, function() {
      console.debug("Foo, Load End");
  });

  map.addLayers([gmap, tiled]);

  map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

  gmap.mapObject.mapTypes.set('styled', styledMapType);
  gmap.mapObject.setMapTypeId('styled');

}
```

Comment: can you try with removing stylez of google map? or try to raiseLayer which name is tiled...

Comment: i will try to remove styles from google ... quez: how riseLayers (order in array of addLayers method??)

Comment: no way ... removing styles does nothing ! same effect ... ;(

Comment: nobody knows ?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using openlayers from github trunk, no more "google" footer.